# Query Script Datasource not updating on change

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a table that has a button on each row to assign a arrival boolean and timestamp on the record in the row. When I click the button that record is not showing as updated on the client. If I refresh the browser or use a button to reload the datasource, the changes are seen.

The datasource model is Guests with a query script datasource of Guests_unchecked. The query script only displays guests that have not arrived, thus widget.datasource.item.arrived = false.

When I click the check in button this script is fired.

```
widget.datasource.item.arrived = true;
widget.datasource.item.arrival_timestamp = new Date();
widget.datasource.load();
```

No updates to the datasource appear until I reload the page.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: For starters could you please tell us if the datasource has 'Auto Save' enabled?

Comment: Yes Auto save is enabled.

Comment: @MarkusMalessa It appears that the call to reload is happening before the datasource finishes updating. Adding a delay fixes the problem. Is there a callback that I can fire when the datasource has been updated?

Comment: I suppose I am wondering why you are reloading the datasource at all, in a case like this, the values for each field should just update after running the code first on the client then on the server and the binding on your fields should make sure that they are in sync. So, I was under the impression that your reload should not be needed even in this case.

Comment: I agree with your assessment and it's quite possible that I am doing this incorrectly. The datasource is a query script returning all records that are incomplete. Each record has a button that when clicked, mark the record as complete. This updates the datasource on the server but the client still sees the record and can keep clicking the complete button. Is it possible to just remove the record from displaying on the client and not have to reload the database? I appreciate the help, Thank You.

Comment: Yes, but I don't necessarily like just hiding elements like a table row, because the hidden table row record would still be stored in `datasource.items`. At this point in time your choices are to either use the JS function `setTimeout(function() {widget.datasource.load();}, 2000)`, which I don't always like either because you cannot accurately predict how much time it takes for the record to update. You may switch the datasource to 'Manual Save' mode and implement `widget.datasource.saveChanges(function() {widget.datasource.load()})`. Or do update server side with success handler.